# Out of universe, how does Geordi's visor work?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I understand how Geordi's visor works in universe, but what about out of universe? How does Levar Burton see with that contraption covering his eyes?

Comment: The answer can be found in the [theme song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=844DzynPG-w) to *Reading Rainbow*:  "**I can do anything**; Take a look, it's in a book, a *Reading Rainbow*."  The visor beams a Reading Rainbow directly into his brain, which allows him to do anything.

Comment: @WadCheber: Some comments are just so bad people should automatically lose rep for even considering posting them.  Like that one.

Comment: @Tango - Flagged for doubting the power of the reading rainbow.  Butterfly in the sky, I can go twice as high.

Comment: @WadCheber [No man should have power like that!](https://youtu.be/VQ34s3kKFDY).

Comment: Just reading your title, I thought you were asking how Geordi's visor actually worked out of universe, and I was thinking, "It doesn't! It's just a prop!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a grid. You can see through the gaps.

[image]

And if you scroll along to 1:40 in this "[making of](http://www.startrek.com/watch_video/making-of-tng-props-geordis-visor-the)" video from StarTrek.com, you can see what the view is like from the inside:

[image]

That being said, Levar Burton said it [wasn't easy](http://www.avclub.com/article/levar-burton-on-tiger-woods-geordi-la-forge-and-re-84292):

> **AVC:** *Even with the visor being hard to see through?*
>
> **LB:** ***Yes, the visor was really hard to see through,*** but guess what? It made me a better actor. Trying to communicate with people
>   without them being able to see your eyes is not easy, I learned.

Comment: Great answer. I can't tell there are gaps in it while watching the show.  I guess that's the power of standard def television.

Comment: Brings back memories of how there was a particular hairclip that looked almost exactly the same (the idea was the the "teeth" could be closed against each other to fix it in the hair) and kids using it in elementary school to look like Geordi.

Answer (score 7):

The [VISOR](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/VISOR) (Visual Instrument and Sensory Organ Replacement) was actually modeled after a hair barrette.  I remember hearing one person say it was actually molded directly from a barrette and slightly modified.

It's not solid, it has vertical bars that Levar Burton could see through:

[image]

Comment: +1 for defining the acronym.  I always wondered why it was written all upper case in the closed captions.